# How to build omniorb with mingw-w64 on Windows?

Tags: c++, windows, corba, mingw-w64, omniorb

I need your help. We use omniorb in our project, but have difficulties with building it with mingw-w64 on Windows in Qt 4.8.1. May you tell me how did you do that? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I haven't tried omniORB with MinGW-w64, but I do know TAO and TAOX11 both as ORB implementations are tested daily with MinGW-w64. See http://download.dre.vanderbilt.edu for TAO and http://www.remedy.nl/en/taox11 for TAOX11

Comment: @JohnnyWillemsen Could you give contacts of developers who tried omniORB with MinGW-w64 in TAO and TAOX11 ?
I just do not know what else I can do (

Comment: TAO is a different ORB, we did that port, see http://www.theaceorb.nl for our details.